# Tab as a button jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Have tab and 5 tabs for showing content and 1 tab for printing page, how to use print button just to onclick without refreshing page.

```
<div id="maintab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#HATPRO">HATPRO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#modules">Module List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#computer">Computer Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#all">All (Raw Data)</a></li>
        <li class="myTab"><a href="#" onclick="printData()">Print</a></li>
    </ul>

$("#maintab").tabs();
```

And 5 div

```
<div class="ui-widget-content" 
<div class="ui-widget-content" 
<div class="ui-widget-content" 
<div class="ui-widget-content" 
<div class="ui-widget-content"
```

**UPDATE 1**

Sorry about all solutions, but it's not working, because it puts all content of all tabs to current tab when clicking on print button

**UPDATE 2**
I added ui-widget-content for print tab. Now it shows empty page

Comment: In your `onclick` method, do `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your jquery code

```
$(".myTab a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working, because it puts all content of all tabs to current tab when clicking on print button

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this.  In my opinion, this is the most elegant because it doesn't require any JQuery or any modifications of your printData() function.

Change

`<a href="#" onclick="printData()">Print</a>`

to

`<a href="#" onclick="printData(); return false;">Print</a>`

Returning false will stop the page from refreshing, as the event will never bubble up.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working, because it puts all content of all tabs to current tab when clicking on print button

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just added simple button

```
 var textElement = $("<span></span>");
    textElement.append('<button id="printBtn" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print</button>')
    textElement.css('position', 'absolute');
    textElement.css('right', '20px');
    textElement.css('top', '5px');
    $("#maintab").append(textElement);
```

But it's ugly solution :(
Thanks everybody for efforts, if there any different solutions, just post or comment :)